# What is the difference between memory usage of fetchone vs fetchall vs looping over the cursor?

Tags: python, pyodbc

What is the memory usage difference assuming there are huge number of rows returned by the SQL query:

`1.`

```py
while True:
      row=cursor.fetchone()
      if not row:
          break
      print(row.user_name)
```

`2.`

```
rows=cursor.fetchall()
for r in rows:
    print(r.user_name)
```

`3.`

```
for r in cursor.execute('SELECT QUERY HERE'):
    print(r.user_name)
```

I'm reading that fetchall returns all rows and so this consumes most memory (option 2).

Where as options 1 and 3 work on each item. But in this case, won't all rows need to be brought into memory for looping? Or does it fetch 1 row from the db in each loop?

Comment: There are no promises about whether the `fetch` APIs transfer one or multiple records.  Option #2 is going to store all of the record in your list, which will clearly use a lot of memory, but not necessarily in the database connector.  Option #3 is not valid.  Where did you see that?

Comment: I saw the example here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started; can you tell me why loading into list takes more memory then accessing one by one? In both cases result has the be stored in memory, no? Or does options 1 and 3 do a yield behavior? Or maybe return 1 row from the sql database via 1 query at a time?

Comment: Disregarding the SQL connector overhead, in the first example you fetch a row and throw it away.  You only need memory for one row.  In the second example, `rows` will be a list that contains the entire contents of the query -- all of the rows are in your memory.

Comment: And I see you are right and I am wrong -- option #3 is valid for pyodbc.  It does not work with the other SQL connectors.

Comment: In first example do you mean to say that suppose there are 50 rows then the pyodbc will fire 50 sql queries? Otherwise how does it return 1 row each time?

Comment: Not 50 queries, but 50 trips to the server.  Most of the major databases have the concept of a "cursor".  The client makes one query, but just reads one row at a time.  The query is usually the time-consuming part, so it works out well.  However, that's only one possible implementation.  You can't tell without looking at the source code for the specific database connector you are using.